# Best way to create a Wordpress plugin with div class

Tags: php, wordpress

At the moment I am developing a new Wordpress plugin for my own website. The goal I want to achieve is to get information from external api call save this to the database and afterwards to show this data in a table in Wordpress.

This is my current code :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: API Plugin
Plugin URI:
Description: A first plugin
Author: 
Version: 1.0
Author URI:
*/

add_action('admin_menu', 'myfirstplugin_admin_actions');

function myfirstplugin_admin_actions(){
    add_options_page('MyFirstPlugin', 'MyFirstPlugin', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'myfirstplugin_admin');
}

function myfirstplugin_admin(){


?>
<div class="wrap">
<h4>A more interesting hello world</h4>
<table class="widefat">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> POST TILE </th>
<th> POST ID </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th> POST TILE </th>
<th> POST ID </th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    $mytestdrafts = $wpdb->get_results(
        "
        SELECT ID, post_title
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_status = 'inherit'
        "
        );
?>
<?php
    foreach ($mytestdrafts as $mytestdraft) {
?>
    <tr>
<?php
    echo "<td>".$mytestdraft->post_title."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$mytestdraft->ID."</td>";
?>
    </tr>
<?php   
    }
?>
</tbody>
</div>
<?php
}

add_shortcode( 'test', 'myfirstplugin_admin' );

?>
```

This is very complex and hard to maintain in the future. When this code has more lines of code. So my questions which alternatives are there inside Wordpress to achieve the same goal?

My goals summarised:

```
  - get data from api and save this in Wordpress database
  - read data from Wordpress database
  - backend php function to read data from database and put it in div class
  - show it in the frontend
```

Comment: do you know oop?,do you know how to use git?

Comment: Where is your code regarding your requirements ?

Comment: @madalinivascu I know how to use git. But in the wordpress world i am new so i do not know how i can make this word in OOP.

Comment: You can run through the api and save it to the database using AJAX, this will make sure, that your scripting won't timeout if you serve it in batches. - you can read it from the database with normal wordpress functions, OR you can show the response from the AJAX, or create your own PDO statements to get it from the DB.

Comment: @Dipak at the moment this is the full source code. But the way how i did this to get data into the divs are not the best method. So i am searching for a better method to start with so i can create my code the good way instead this way since this way its hard to maintain if the lines increases

Comment: @Stender i can make a function to save the data into the database. But the problem is how to show this in the front end in a div class with multiple columns and rows.

Comment: why not use a boilerplate plugin?

Comment: @madalinivascu the problem is to show the data in div without without complex php.

Comment: what are you saving it as? posts? a custom post type? You could loop through them with a query and a post while setup

Comment: @Stender i am saving it as posts

Comment: Do you have a way of identifying them from the normal posts? like a category, tag or something like that? If you don't want them in your normal loop, I would save them in a custom post type.

Comment: to problem is not the loop but showing the post in table in the front end the easiest way to do this. In my code you will see that this is hard to maintain if the lines of code increases